# Cant set state from function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, setstate

## Can't Set State

I'm trying to set my state's `randomUserDataName` to `randomUser.Name` that I retrieve from another function
But cant set state data from I retrieve `getRandomUser` function

```
function getRandomUser() {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
  ref.limitToLast(1).on(
    //"value",
    "child_added",
    function (snapshot) {
      () => console.log("after this log is current user's data");
      var randomUser = snapshot.val();
      var randomUserDataName = randomUser.Name;
      var randomUserDataLastName = randomUser.LastName;
      var randomUserDataAge = randomUser.Age;
      var randomUserDataBio = randomUser.Bio;
      console.log(randomUserDataName);
      console.log(randomUserDataAge);
    },
    function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    }
  );
}
```

Here the get user's data function

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      randomUserDataName: "",
      randomUserDataLastName: "",
      randomUserDataBio: "",
      randomUserDataAge: "",
      randomUserDataInstagram: "",
      currentuserUID: "",
    };
  }

## here the my class's state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use setState. Please better take a look into docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: im using setState like this: this.setState({ randomUserDataName: randomUserDataName });
but i get:"cant find variable randomUserDataName ".
where do i have to put setState code

Comment: @TunaGündüz, you can choose whats best for you, you can put in a class method, or function and call it from some event... pretty close what you did. Just remember, state in React is immutable so for class components you have to use setState. About the error, you are getting it because you did not set it anywhere! So ask yourself: Where randomUserDataName comes from?